# Execute command when sequence of keys is pressed

Tags: linux, keyboard

I would like to execute a specific command when a sequence of keys is pressed. For example when the user writes at any point the string 'cake', play a sound or video, or lock the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Autokey

Allows you to trigger python scripts by entering abbreviations. [See their installation guide](https://github.com/autokey/autokey#installation).

Once installed, you'll want to add a new script, enter an **abbreviation** for it, which can be any string(such as **cake**), then write a Python script to do what you're wanting to do. To play a sound on Linux, you could:

```
import os
os.popen('xdg-open /full/path/to/sound')
```

Note that this will open the file in the "default" audio player program and will focus on the window. Nevertheless, the os library is versatile and you'll likely make use of it if you go with Autokey or Python. Here's a way to lock the screen in Linux:

```
os.popen('xdg-screensaver lock')
```